# Creating a matrix from multiple column vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I create a matrix from multiple column vectors?

I know that I can easily create a data frame with column vectors:

```
> colA <- 1:5
> colB <- 21:25
> colC <- 31:35
> data.frame(colA, colB, colC)
  colA colB colC
1    1   21   31
2    2   22   32
3    3   23   33
4    4   24   34
5    5   25   35
```

However, when I try `matrix()`, it gives me unexpected results, as shown below. How can create my desired matrix? I know I can do `as.matrix(df)`, which nicely preserves the column names, but I'm looking for a more direct approach.

```
> matrix(colA, colB, colC)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    1    2    3    4     5     1     2     3
 [2,]    2    3    4    5    1    2    3    4    5     1     2     3     4
 [3,]    3    4    5    1    2    3    4    5    1     2     3     4     5
 [4,]    4    5    1    2    3    4    5    1    2     3     4     5     1
 [5,]    5    1    2    3    4    5    1    2    3     4     5     1     2
 [6,]    1    2    3    4    5    1    2    3    4     5     1     2     3
 [7,]    2    3    4    5    1    2    3    4    5     1     2     3     4
 [8,]    3    4    5    1    2    3    4    5    1     2     3     4     5
 [9,]    4    5    1    2    3    4    5    1    2     3     4     5     1
[10,]    5    1    2    3    4    5    1    2    3     4     5     1     2
[11,]    1    2    3    4    5    1    2    3    4     5     1     2     3
[12,]    2    3    4    5    1    2    3    4    5     1     2     3     4
[13,]    3    4    5    1    2    3    4    5    1     2     3     4     5
[14,]    4    5    1    2    3    4    5    1    2     3     4     5     1
[15,]    5    1    2    3    4    5    1    2    3     4     5     1     2
[16,]    1    2    3    4    5    1    2    3    4     5     1     2     3
[17,]    2    3    4    5    1    2    3    4    5     1     2     3     4
[18,]    3    4    5    1    2    3    4    5    1     2     3     4     5
[19,]    4    5    1    2    3    4    5    1    2     3     4     5     1
[20,]    5    1    2    3    4    5    1    2    3     4     5     1     2
[21,]    1    2    3    4    5    1    2    3    4     5     1     2     3
      [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25]
 [1,]     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5
 [2,]     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1
 [3,]     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2
 [4,]     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3
 [5,]     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4
 [6,]     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5
 [7,]     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1
 [8,]     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2
 [9,]     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3
[10,]     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4
[11,]     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5
[12,]     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1
[13,]     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2
[14,]     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3
[15,]     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4
[16,]     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5
[17,]     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1
[18,]     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2
[19,]     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3
[20,]     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4
[21,]     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5
      [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31]
 [1,]     1     2     3     4     5     1
 [2,]     2     3     4     5     1     2
 [3,]     3     4     5     1     2     3
 [4,]     4     5     1     2     3     4
 [5,]     5     1     2     3     4     5
 [6,]     1     2     3     4     5     1
 [7,]     2     3     4     5     1     2
 [8,]     3     4     5     1     2     3
 [9,]     4     5     1     2     3     4
[10,]     5     1     2     3     4     5
[11,]     1     2     3     4     5     1
[12,]     2     3     4     5     1     2
[13,]     3     4     5     1     2     3
[14,]     4     5     1     2     3     4
[15,]     5     1     2     3     4     5
[16,]     1     2     3     4     5     1
[17,]     2     3     4     5     1     2
[18,]     3     4     5     1     2     3
[19,]     4     5     1     2     3     4
[20,]     5     1     2     3     4     5
[21,]     1     2     3     4     5     1
Warning message:
In matrix(colA, colB, colC) :
  data length [5] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [21]
```

Comment: `cbind(colA, colB, colC)` should work.

Comment: Thanks. You should answer the question so I can mark your solution. And why doesn't matrix(colA, colB, colC) not work?

Comment: your call to matrix(colA, colB, colC) is interpreted in R as matrix(data=colA, nrow=colB, ncol=colC) this is why you have 21 rows and 31 columns as R apparently only takes the first row of data provided to nrow and ncol as the number of rows/columns.

look at help(matrix) for how the arguments are passed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `cbind` to produce the desired matrix:

```
mat <- cbind(colA, colB, colC)
mat
#      colA colB colC
# [1,]    1   21   31
# [2,]    2   22   32
# [3,]    3   23   33
# [4,]    4   24   34
# [5,]    5   25   35
class(mat)
# [1] "matrix"
```

You don't get the matrix you're expecting with the call of `matrix(colA, colB, colC)`, because your arguments are getting interpreted as the first, second, and third arguments to the `matrix` function (aka `data`, `nrow`, and `ncol`). If you wanted to use the matrix function, you would need to provide your data as a single argument, with something like `mat <- matrix(c(colA, colB, colC), ncol=3)`. If you used this syntax, you would not get the column names from the variables like we did with `cbind`.